# When is it time to move on from WordPress?

Tags: performance, wordpress, blog

My company's blog it closing in on 30,000 posts and get around 1,000,000 visits a month. Things seem slow even though we have a good server.

At what point to you move on from WordPress or does it not matter? Would I have better luck splitting the DB?

Comment: I think this question does not fit stackoverflow since it is non programming related and, at least, argumentative. [Wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com/) has blogs that long, long crossed the 1M hits / month mark. You can find a lot of info about tunning WordPress over the web ([start here](http://www.intenseblog.com/wordpress/optimize-wordpress-speed.html)) and seek further help from experienced system administrators at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Define "good server." Beyond that, what @ceejayoz said.

Comment: You might want to also look at the [Wordpress stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 11):

WordPress is likely not the issue. It can easily handle that much traffic (1,000,000 visits a month is less than one every two seconds) and that many posts.

You need to figure out what's actually causing slowdowns. It might be your host, your database, a misconfiguration, a bad plugin, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Like the others said, Wordpress can handle this amount of traffic just fine.

I would suggest one of the two caching plugins. These plugins write database-heavy pages to disk, which saves load on the database server. The difference is remarkable.

[WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/)

[W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/)

Both are well-maintained, the latter has more features, but can be intimidating.

If caching doesn't seem to help much, your problem might be in different areas. Web server configuration can be tweaked (adding gzip compression, adding Expires headers) and even theme HTML has an impact (seek to minimize the amount of requests your page is doing). I would need detailed information to help you out.

Comment: I'd agree with this, but say you could go even further than simply caching - using a CDN, implementing a server to manage load-balancing, installing Varnish, a dedicated SQL/DB server etc...It's your infrastructure thats letting you down, not the software.

Answer (score 4):

Here are couple of things which you can do to optimize your site for high traffic:

1. Optimize Database: delete post revision, delete all trashed posts
2. Use dedicated server.
3. Use Cache mechanism like W3TC
4. Use CDN and cloudflare
5. use Sub-domains if you can.
6. Limit the number of plugins
7. Less custom php call, use a light weight Wp theme.

Comment: What benefit does using subdomains have?

Comment: Increases the number of Simultaneous Http requests, if done correctly. See http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html for more suggestions.

Comment: Also you'd be best going with a dedicated server for web and another for DB at a minimum, scaling out with more web servers and load balancer if site demanded it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try some caching plugins. Wordpress shouldn't be that slow; it's very optimized. The only thing faster than Wordpress would really be an HTML website, which is basically a caching plugin.